# Dictionaries [String: [String]] in Swift

Tags: arrays, swift, dictionary, value-type

I have a dictionary that looks like this:

```
var dict = [String: [String]]()
```

I want to be able to add multiple arrays for a single key. This works fine:

```
dict["hello"] = ["item 1"]
```

But when I assign a new array the previous value is obviously overwritten - we want to avoid that:

```
dict["hello"] = ["item 2"] // overwrites item 1 – how to avoid overwriting?
```

So I tried to use the `append` method, but this returns nil:

```
dict["hello"]?.append("test") // does nothing? output: ()
```

How can I append strings to the array (value) of a certain key in Swift?

Comment: `dict["hello"] = dict["hello"]?.append("test")`?

Comment: @Larme This returns `Cannot subscript a value of type 'inout [String: [String]]`

Comment: (dict["hello"] as? [String]).append("AnyValue")

Comment: @UsamaSadiq Returns `Downcast from [String]? to [String] only unwraps optionals`

Comment: `as` instead of `as?` to fix that error

Comment: @Cesare Kindly check the answer . Let me know if it works for you

Comment: This is an interesting read for how to make dictionaries mutable https://oleb.net/blog/2017/01/dictionary-key-paths/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### First of all...

... you don't really want this

> I want to be able to add multiple arrays for a single key.

Instead I think you want...

> ... to add a string to the array associated to a given string

### Example

In other words you want to go from this

```
["hello":["item 1"]]
```

to this

```
["hello":["item 1", "item 2"]]]
```

### So, how to do it?

Let's begin with your dictionary

```
var dict = [String: [String]]()
dict["hello"] = ["item 1"]
```

Now you need to extract the array associated to the `hello` key

```
var list = dict["hello"] ?? []
```

adding a string to it

```
list.append("item 2")
```

and finally adding the updated array back into the dictionary

```
dict["hello"] = list
```

That's it

Answer (score 4):

**This is what your code does**

`dict["hello"] = ["item 1"]` - This sets `hello` to `["item 1"]`

`dict["hello"] = ["item 2"]` - This sets `hello` to `["item 2"]`

This is just like a variable, for example:

```
var hello = Array<String>()

hello = ["item 1"] // prints out ["item 1"]

hello = ["item 2"] // prints out ["item 2"]
```

This is what is happening with your dictionary. You are overriding any stored data with new data.

---

The problem with appending. This only works if there is already an array at that key.

`dict["hello"]?.append("test")` This wouldn't work.

But this would.

```
dict["hello"] = ["test 1"]

dict["hello"]?.append("test")

print(dict) // prints out ["dict":["test 1","test"]]
```

---

**What you need to do**

```
var dict = Dictionary<String,Array<String>>()

func add(string:String,key:String) {

    if var value = dict[key] {

        // if an array exist, append to it

        value.append(string)

        dict[key] = value

    } else {

        // create a new array since there is nothing here

        dict[key] = [string]
    }
}

add(string: "test1", key: "hello")

add(string: "test2", key: "hello")

add(string: "test3", key: "hello")

print(dict) // ["hello": ["test1", "test2", "test3"]]
```

---

**Dictionary Extension**

```
extension Dictionary where Key == String, Value == Array<String> {

    mutating func append(_ string:String, key:String) {

        if var value = self[key] {

            // if an array exist, append to it

            value.append(string)

            self[key] = value

        } else {

            // create a new array since there is nothing here

            self[key] = [string]
        }
    }
}
```

**How to use**

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    var dict = Dictionary<String,Array<String>>()

    dict.append("first", key: "hello")

    dict.append("second", key: "hello")

    dict.append("thrid", key: "hello")

    dict.append("one", key: "goodbye")

    dict.append("two", key: "goodbye")

    print(dict) // ["hello": ["first", "second", "thrid"], "goodbye": ["one", "two"]]
}
```

Comment: Pretty neat, Tristan! Could this be further developed into an extension?

Comment: I have added the extension. @Cesare

Answer (score 1):

Please try this thing and let me know if this is what you require

```
    import UIKit

    var dict = [String: [String]]()
if var value = dict["hello"]{
    value.append("Hi")
    dict["hello"] = value
}else{
    dict["hello"] = ["item 1"]
}
```

Comment: While this works if there is at least a value for a certain key, I want to be able to set the value for a key regardless if the dictionary contains a value for a specific key or not.

Comment: you can set the new value in else block. check the edited code

Answer (score 1):

Other people have the correct solution. Here is a quick shorthand for the same answer.

```
var dict = [String: [String]]()

dict["hello"] = (dict["hello"] ?? []) + ["item 1"]
dict["hello"] = (dict["hello"] ?? []) + ["item 2"]
```

In Swift 4, this will be

```
var dict = [String: [String]]()

dict["hello"] = dict["hello", default: []] + ["item 1"]
dict["hello"] = dict["hello", default: []] + ["item 2"]
```

Comment: In Swift 4, just `dict["hello", default: []].append("item 1")` :)

Comment: `No + candidates produce the expected contextual result type [String]`

Comment: @Cesare hmm… don't know what to say. This test in Xcode 8.3.1 playground and Xcode 9 Beta playground. It uses [the `+` operator for Arrays](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/CollectionTypes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH8-ID502).